Restrict possible transformations for estimateAffinePartial2D
I am using estimateAffinePartial2D to match stitch two images together. Sometimes I get a completely wrong result (scaled way too much, rotated way too much, ...) as my cameras are handheld, certain movements are impossible (like upside down, ...). Is there a way to restrict the possible transformations which estimateAffinePartial2D can make? Is there any other method which might be better suited?
I know I could just limit (min,max) the output transformation but this will still get me something wrong. I want to reduce the possible solutions to help estimateAffinePartial2D find the best solution.
